# Stopping a Sub process without closing the Service

Tags: powershell, service

I am using PowerShell start-process command to run a ps1 file as a service. Following is the line to start this process:

```
start-process PowerShell.exe -arg C:\scripts\scrtip_name.ps1 -WindowStyle Hidden
```

How do I stop "JUST THIS EXECTUTION" without completely shutting down PowerShell service, since it might be used for other processes at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the PID if you use `Start-Process` with the `-PassThru` flag  like this:

```
$app = start-process PowerShell.exe -arg C:\scripts\scrtip_name.ps1 -WindowStyle Hidden - PassThru
```

And then close the process like this:

```
Stop-Process $app.Id
```

Regards

Comment: Seems like a solution. Quick question. Does the process ID remains same? Also, How do I pass it to another script which I will use to execute this command "Stop-Process $app.Id"

Comment: @nitinsh99 yes the process id does not change during runtime. You can pass the PID as an argument to another script (without knowing what you want to do i can only give general info)

Comment: My end goal is to run a powershell script to stop the execution of the process which I started by running above mentioned command.